# Learning about multithreading. Tried to make a prime number finder

Tags: c++, multithreading, primes

I'm studying for a uni project and one of the requirements is to include multithreading.  I decided to make a prime number finder and - while it works - it's rather slow.  My best guess is that this has to do with the amount of threads I'm creating and destroying.

My approach was to take the range of primes that are below N, and distribute these evenly across M threads (where M = number of cores (in my case 8)), however these threads are being created and destroyed every time N increases.

Pseudocode looks like this:

```
for each core
  # new thread
  for i in (range / numberOfCores) * currentCore
    if !possiblePrimeIsntActuallyPrime
      if  possiblePrime % i == 0
        possiblePrimeIsntActuallyPrime = true
        return
    else
      return
```

Which does work, but 8 threads being created for every possible prime seems to be slowing the system down.

Any suggestions on how to optimise this further?

Comment: Don't destroy the threads. Reuse them. Establish a Thread Pool.

Comment: What about if you have a synchronized method that simply generates increasing numbers, starting from a random point in the range. Then each worker thread can try to check if a number is a prime (a tough enough assignment) and then ask for a new number from the method, until you find a prime?

Comment: A thread pool would work, but it's probably overkill -- an easier method would just be to spawn M threads, and have the first thread check the first possible prime, then the (first+M) possible prime, then (first+(2*M)), then (first+(3*M)), and so on..... the second thread would check the (first+M+1) possible prime, then (first+(2*M)+1), then (first+(3*M)+1), and so on... then the M threads would just run forever, printing out any primes they discovered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use thread pooling.

Create 8 threads and store them in an array. Feed it new data each time one ends and start it again. This will prevent them from having to be created and destroyed each time.

Also, when calculating your range of numbers to check, only check up to `ceil(sqrt(N))` as anything after that is guaranteed to either not go into it or the other corresponding factor has already been checked. i.e. `ceil(sqrt(24))` is 5.

Once you check 5 you don't need to check anything else because 6 goes into 24 4 times and 4 has been checked, 8 goes into it 3 times and 3 has been checked, etc.